# Flutter video_player not playing video saved to application directory

Tags: flutter

UPDATE: ***I have confirmed the file is there and works, just not using the video_player.  It just never initializes and when I debug from xcode, it does not throw and errors.***
I am using the image_picker plugin and have modified it to pick videos as well.  All works fine on initial selection of video and playing int he video_player.  All work on iOS right now.  However I base64 encode the video and send to server via JSON.  If I decode on server and play the video via http all works fine, however client wants then videos to be synced to device for offline viewing.  When I take the JSON from the server and decode and save to the Applications Directory all works fine, however video_player will not play the video, it will not even initialize the video.  Is there something I am missing as it relates to iOS to get this to work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this, I believe I have the same issue on android.

Comment: The work around so far is to go into the android file and force the is local to default to true. I have not had time to fix it, bit for some reason no matter what you pass for islocal it passes over the method channel as false.

Comment: @Robert Please update this thread if you are able to find the fix. Trying to figure out though.

Comment: @Robert Were you able to figure this out? Facing the same issue in android even with the latest flutter and video_player

Comment: I guess Robert gave up flutter because they don't solve this kind of bugs for years ))

Answer (score 0):

my _controller.value.intialize is false or local video from cache but for network video is true  and working fine on iOS

edit:
use the recent version with the XFile  type and it assign
path automatically we don't have to manage and join .. too bad it isn't mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. The video would play correctly in android, but did not even initialize in ios. Spent 4 days trying to solve this problem.
For me the root cause was that my downloaded video file had SPACES in them. Removed all the spaces with 
`myFilePath.replaceAll(RegExp('\\s+'), '_');` 
and it was working correctly.